# Implementar Callback al hacer click a un boton de un modulo en Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo un modulo personalizado de Android `NativeBannerView` intento que al hacer click en un botón delegue la acción asignada des de el proyecto, no domino bien el tema de interfaces, callbacks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/smart_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/banner_height">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
        android:src="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dentro del modulo detecto el click:

```
Button btnCloseBanner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
if (btnCloseBanner != null) {
    btnCloseBanner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //delegar funcionalidad asignada desde el proyecto
        }
    });
}
```

En el proyecto

```
myBanner = (NativeBannerView) findViewById(R.id.banner_view);
```

mi idea seria al interceptar el click del botón que se encuentra dentro del modulo, y se lance un `Toast` des de el proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como has mencionado puedes crear un interface para pasar los datos entre distintas clases, fragments, views.. Te dejo el enlace de la documentacion mas a bajo que lo describen bastante bien.
Declarar un interface es bastante simple, en la clase que quieres usar, en tu caso "NativeBannerView" declaras un interface, por ejemplo...

```
 public interface myListener {

 }
```

Dentro de la interfaz tenemos de definir los metodos que tendra. Por ejemplo, en tu caso necesitas un metodo para cuando se haga click en el boton, entonces declaramos un metodo que llamaremos cuando se pulse el boton.

Añadimos:

```
 public interface myListener {
     void onBotonPulsado();
 }
```

Ahora al principio de nuestra clase, definimos una nueva variable de tipo myListener.

```
myListener listener;
```

Añadimos un metodo para setear el listener,

```
 public void setListener(myListener listener){
     this.listener = listener;
 }
```

Una vez añadido el listener, podemos llamarlo desde la parte del codigo que queramos, en tu caso cuando se pulsa el boton.

```
Button btnCloseBanner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
if (btnCloseBanner != null) {
    btnCloseBanner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //delegar funcionalidad asignada desde el proyecto
           listener.onBotonPulsado();
        }
    });
}
```

Ahora solo queda añadir el listener en la clase principal, o donde tenemos el "NativeBannerView", algo como...

```
myBanner = (NativeBannerView) findViewById(R.id.banner_view);
myBanner.setListener(new NativeBannerView.myListener(){
   public void onBotonPulsado(){
      // Y aqui puedes ya hacer lo que quieras
   }
});
```

Enlace a la documentacion:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html